# passing functors by reference , i run it on VS2012,why does it make errors?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, stl

Here is my code:
result should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,but it is still 1,2,3,1,2,3.when i run it on linux, it is correct. who can tell me the truth.

```
class IntSequence {
private:
    int value;
public:
    IntSequence(int initialValue) : value(initialValue){}
    int operator() () {
        return value++;
    }
};
int main()
{

    list<int> coll;
    IntSequence seq(1);
    generate_n<back_insert_iterator<list<int> > , int , IntSequence& >
         (back_inserter(coll) , 3 ,seq);//result is 1,2,3
    generate_n (back_inserter(coll) , 3 ,seq);//result should be 1,2,3,4,5,6,but it is still 1,2,3,1,2,3
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `std::ref`, otherwise `generate_n` will create a new `IntSequence` functor, increase it's value, and then destroy it.

http://ideone.com/pBHum1

```
list<int> coll;
IntSequence seq(1);

generate_n (back_inserter(coll), 3, std::ref(seq));
generate_n (back_inserter(coll), 3, std::ref(seq));

for (auto& i : coll)
   cout << i << " ";
```

Explanation why it doesn't work in visual studio:

In VS2015 (and in your case 2012), `generate_n` calls an internal private function `_generate_n`, which doesn't accept a forwarding reference, or a reference at all. Instead, it accepts a `_Fn` by value again.

So even tho you actually passed a reference properly by explicitly setting the template arguments, it's gone with the following call to `_generate_n`.

I don't know if this is meant to be this way. But probably it is, since this is the reason why `std::reference_wrapper` exists in the first place.

Comment: @songyuanyao it works well now use this code with vs

Comment: @songyuanyao I've updated my answer. I don't know if this is a bug.